# При появление новых элементов с absolute браузер не расстягивает общий контейнер

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

[image]

При маленьком разрешении, при клике на лайк, появляется окно для комментария с position:absolute с появлением окна появляется скролл, но браузер (фф 3,6) не расстягивает общий контейнер под новый размер окна и мы видим фон body. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может overflow-x: hidden; хотя хз, нужно видеть код.

Comment: так обрежет кусок, ну и скролл пропадет при любом размере окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И не будет растягивать. Абсолютные элементы на размер не влияют, увы. В качестве решения можно предложить растягивать яваскриптом.

Comment: времени нет гадать, будем вставлять js-заглушку

Comment: от js решения отказался, пришлось опять парсить виджет, вставлять в тело страницы свой цсс файл и грузить его также во фрейме, уменьшил размер блока и сделал его по центру от кнопки, перенес уголочек тоже в центр, теперь блок не вылазит за основную область